# VHDL signal assignment leads to uninitialized state

Tags: vhdl

I am implementing the Booth's algorithm for multiplying two numbers (in unsigned 2's complement form) in VHDL. Unfortunately, I am very poor at VHDL and can't figure out where I am going wrong.
**The Problem** : On stepping through the simulation, I noticed that when I had assigned a value of "1011" to y, the signal mult got "0UUU". I can't understand why that happens. Here is my code :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

-- x, y are the n bit numbers to be multiplied.
-- The Algorithm :
-- U = 0, prev_bit = 0;
-- for i = 1 to n do
-- if start of a string of 1's in Y then U = U - X
-- if end of a string of 1's in Y then U = U + X
-- Arithmetic right shift UV
-- Circular right shift Y and copy Y(0) to prev_bit

entity booth is 
  generic(N : natural := 4);
  port(
    x, y : in std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
    result : out std_logic_vector(2*N-1 downto 0);
    clk : in std_logic 
  );
end booth;

architecture booth_arch of booth is
  --temp is equivalent to UV where UV is the result.
  signal temp : std_logic_vector(2*N-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
  --prev_bit to compare for starting and ending of strings of 1's.
  signal prev_bit : std_logic := '0';
  signal mult : std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);

  begin 
    process(x, y)
      begin
        mult <= y;
        prev_bit <= '0';
        for i in 0 to N-1 loop  
          if(mult(0) = '1' and prev_bit = '0') then   --start of a string of 1's
            temp(2*N-1 downto N) <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(temp(2*N-1 downto N)) + unsigned(not(x)) + 1);
          elsif(mult(0) = '0' and prev_bit = '1') then --end of a string of 1's
            temp(2*N-1 downto N) <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(temp(2*N-1 downto N)) + unsigned(x));
          end if;      
        prev_bit <= mult(0);
        mult(N-2 downto 0) <= mult(N-1 downto 1);   --circular right shift y.
        mult(N-1) <= prev_bit;
        temp(2*N-2 downto 0) <= temp(2*N-1 downto 1);  --arithmetic right shift temp.
       end loop; 
       result <= temp; 
  end process;     
end booth_arch;
```

P.S : The clk signal is redundant here. I haven't used it yet.

Answer (score 1):

If your ports and internal signals are unsigned, declare them `unsigned`, for a start. At least you are using the correct numeric_std library. Use the strong type system instead of fighting against it!

Then you may need to initialise `Temp` at the start of each multiplication, (as you already do for `Mult, Prev_Bit`) instead of once at the start of simulation. At the moment it seems possible for `Temp` to contain stale values from a previous multiply (such as `UUUU` * `UUUU`).

Thirdly you tell us what you have assigned to `Y`, but we don't yet know what you are assigning to `X` which could still be `UUUU` for all I know.

Writing a minimal VHDL testbench and adding it to the question would be a good way of getting further help - or, more likely, discovering the real cause of the problem yourself!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Brian's comments: you are reading and writing the signal mult in the same combinational process. Unless your *really* know what you are doing, you shouldn't do this. After synthesis, you will get things that do not correspond to what your simulator does.

Also, you should be aware that the value that you assign to `mult` (in the first line of your process) won't be visible until after the process finishes and starts a new iteration. In VHDL -speak we say that the new value is available after one *delta cycle*.

Comment: By "_really_ know what you are doing" you mean: We keep in mind that `mult` signal still holds the old value when we read it, even though we assigned a new value to it?

I am also beginner...